# Error building CNN model, target size is different than sample size

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to use an exiting CNN model tutorial with my own dataset, since I'm new to deeplearning and I want to understand the concept.

The thing I don't get is the label y values. How to train the Model to give label y to each sample x? is there a better way to load my data with labels to cnn other than using for lop?

I have a data set of 5 animals, consists of 1725 (overall). for example, dog = 3 images. cats = 54 images.

every time I try to run my model I get this error:

```
ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 5172 input samples and 1725 target samples.
```

This is the inputs

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os 
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras
from keras.utils import to_categorical


IMG_SIZE = 64

PATH = os.getcwd()
data_path = PATH + '\image'
data_dir_list = os.listdir(data_path)

num_classes = 5
img_data_list = []
num_channel=1



for dataset in data_dir_list:
    img_list=os.listdir(data_path+'/'+ dataset)
    print ('Loaded the images of dataset-'+'{}\n'.format(dataset))
    for img in img_list:
        input_img=cv2.imread(data_path + '/'+ dataset + '/'+ img )
        input_img=cv2.cvtColor(input_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        input_img_resize=cv2.resize(input_img,(64,64))
        img_data_list.append(input_img_resize)

img_data = np.array(img_data_list)
img_data = img_data.astype('float32')
img_data /= 255
print(img_data.size)
print (img_data.shape)
```

after I run it

```
Loaded the images of dataset-0

Loaded the images of dataset-1

Loaded the images of dataset-2

Loaded the images of dataset-3

Loaded the images of dataset-4

7065600
(1725, 64, 64)
```

if I check the img_data list

```
print(len(img_data))
print(img_data)
1725
[[[0.8784314  0.32941177 0.22745098 ... 0.13333334 0.06666667 0.05490196]
  [0.03137255 0.16862746 0.14901961 ... 0.18431373 0.20784314 0.16470589]
  [0.1764706  0.42745098 0.26666668 ... 0.42352942 0.05882353 0.00784314]
  ...
  [0.42352942 0.4        0.2901961  ... 0.3647059  0.4392157  0.4392157 ]
  [0.38431373 0.4        0.4392157  ... 0.4392157  0.3019608  0.32941177]
  [0.20784314 0.41568628 0.40392157 ... 0.42745098 0.21176471 0.3372549 ]]
```

Here after reshaping the img_data

```
#num_of_samples = 1725 

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import random 
from sklearn.utils import shuffle


num_of_samples = img_data.shape[0]

# convert class labels to on-hot encoding
#Y = np_utils.to_categorical(labels, 5)
#train_labels = keras.utils.to_categorical(labels, num_classes)
nb_train_samples = 1725
train_labels = np.array([0] * (195) + [1] * (120) + [2] * (380) + [3] * (144) + [4] * (886))
train_labels = keras.utils.to_categorical(train_labels, num_classes = 5)

#Shuffle the dataset
x = [] # for images 
y = [] # for labels 
print(train_labels.shape)


x = shuffle(img_data)
print(x.shape)

y = shuffle(train_labels)
print(y.shape)
# Split the dataset
y_train = y.reshape((1725,5))


X_train,X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)

X_train = np.array(X_train).reshape(-1, 32,32, 1)
print (X_train.size)

X_test = np.array(X_test).reshape(-1, 32,32, 1)


print (y_train.size)


print (train_labels)
print (train_labels.size)
```

output

```
(1725, 5)
(1725, 64, 64)
(1725, 5)
```

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [5175, 1725]

```
#Set Model Parameters

batch_size = 15
epochs = 50
num_classes = 5

input_shape=img_data[0].shape


#Build Model 

Model = Sequential()
Model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3,3), input_shape=(32,32,1)))
Model.add(Activation('relu'))
Model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
Model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
Model.add(Activation('relu'))
Model.add(Flatten())
Model.add(Dense(1024))
Model.add(Activation('relu'))
Model.add(Dropout(0.4))
Model.add(Dense(num_classes))
Model.add(Activation('softmax'))



# Model Compiling 

Model.compile(loss = "categorical_crossentropy", optimizer = "Adam", metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding 5175, 1725 * 3 = 5175, so some numpy reshape operation is combining the RGB color channels(3) and the sample count(1725)? Although, that is not the case in the code snippets above since the image is converted to grayscale.

Yes, there is a easier way to load the image data in Keras. Just put the images of each class under its own sub-folder like dog, cat etc. and use the ImageDataGenerator's flow_from_directory method. The other advantage is it also supports data augmentation, normalization etc.

https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/